# What does multiplying an inverse of a quotient ring by a ring mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am attempting to prove that a ring $R$ is the intersection of all $R_p$, where $R_p=S^{-1}R$ for S=R\P and the intersection is over all prime ideals P of R. The trouble right now is that I don't quite understand the statement. I understand that S is a quotient ring, but what does it mean to take $S^{-1}$? And should the product $R_p=S^{-1}R$ be interpreted as a direct product with ordered pairs, or differently?

Comment: $S$ is *not* a ring, since it doesn't have $0$ but it is a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$ and $S^{-1}R$ is a notation for localization at a prime ideal $p.$ Note also that the intersection has to be taken over all prime ideals not containing $p.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $R\color{Red}{/}P$ is a quotient ring. $S=R\color{Red}{\setminus}P=\{x|x\in R\wedge x\not\in P\}$ is the complement of $P$ in $R$.

If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ then $S$ is *multiplicative*: if $s_1,s_2\in S$ then $s_1s_2\in S$. This is important, and you should prove it yourself as a warm-up exercise.

And if $S$ is a multiplicative set, then $S^{-1}R$ is the [localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) of $R$ with respect to $S$. In the case that $R$ is a domain, it has a fraction field $F$, and $S^{-1}R$ is the smallest subring of $F$ containing $R$ and all inverses of elements in $S$. For example if $S=\{s,s^2,s^3\cdots,\}$ then $S^{-1}R=R[s^{-1}]$. In this situation the localizations $R_P=(R\setminus P)^{-1}R$ all lie inside $F={\rm Frac}(R)$ and so you can take their intersection. I am not familiar with what the intersection means if $R$ is not a domain.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've seen this notation in class before, thanks for explaining it. It is an integral domain, but I needed to know what those things meant to even get started.